# How to use IdentityServer4 Access Token and [Authorize] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have the solution with projects: **IdentityServer4**, **ApiServer**, **MvcClient**. I use `Hybrid flow`. Auth works very well but I can't get the `role` in MvcClient.

In the MvсСlient app, after authorization, I get `access_token`. The token contains the necessary claims. But the MVC application cannot access to the user role.

That is, it is assumed that I will call the external API from the MVC application. But I also need the MVC application to be able to use the user role.

> Attribute **[Authorize]** works fine but **[Authorize(Roles =
>   "admin")]** doesn't work!

Source code here: **[gitlab](https://gitlab.com/vorobjevvalera/identity-server4-example)**

Comment: It's hard to understand the reason of your problem without provided source code

Comment: Ok! This project on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/vorobjevvalera/identity-server4-example)

Comment: Add user role to your claims.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Can u provide that claims in your jwt?

Comment: Implement `IProfileService` and add user role in your claims, something like this `claims.Add(new Claim("role", userRole));`.

Comment: I use TestUserProfileService and `new TestUser
                {
                    SubjectId = "2",
                    Username = "bob",
                    Password = "password",

                    Claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("name", "Bob"),
                        new Claim("website", "https://bob.com"),
                        new Claim("role", "admin"),
                    }
                }
            };`

Comment: And use `public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("api1", "API 1",
                    new[] {"name", "role", "website"})
            };
        }`

Comment: I've added link for source code repository. Go to [code](https://gitlab.com/vorobjevvalera/identity-server4-example)

Comment: you can extend your GetIdentityResources() as the following: GetIdentityResources()
        {
            var openIdScope = new IdentityResources.OpenId();
            openIdScope.UserClaims.Add("role");
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                openIdScope,
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            };
        }

Comment: as already mentioned (maybe not clear enough) in the answer to your other question, you have to catch the difference between id_token and token.

Comment: With 2.1 there are some security changes, please read this: https://leastprivilege.com/2018/07/16/beware-the-combined-authorize-filter-mechanics-in-asp-net-core-2-1/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I have not found a better solution than to intercept the Access Token event. Then I parsed it and manually added claims to the cookie.

```
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTokenResponseReceived = xxx =>
                    {
                        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                        JwtSecurityToken jwt = handler.ReadJwtToken(xxx.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);

                        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity) xxx.Principal.Identity;
                        claimsIdentity.AddClaims(jwt.Claims);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
```

I will be very grateful to you! If you look at the source code of the project (it has been updated to asp.net core 2.1) and offer the best option!